# Swim platform supports

Tags: structural-engineering

I have a swim platform on the back of my boat that extends 24” from the transom. It is supported by 5- 1” diameter stainless steel arms that are attached To the transom 13” below the platform and at 2” from the rear of the platform.
I would like to change the platform out for one that is 48” but would like to reuse the stock transom mounting points for the support arms. The new longer arms would therefore go from 13” below the platform back approx. 42” wher they would attach to the new platform.
Is there a way to calculate the new support arm angle and to determine if it will be enough support at the new reduced angle? 
The width of the platform is 128” side to side and the support arms are evenly distributed across the width from about 6” in per side.
I’m here because I’m not an engineer or mathematician so bear with me if I left some crucial data out.
And if I do need to find a local engineer to call this, would it be a structural?
Thanks

Comment: A diagram would help.

Comment: Are the fixing points strong enough?